# Designing an "item stock alert" architecture

Tags: architecture, queue, alert, scaling

I'm struggling to architect a sales application, on which buyers may register item restock alerts. This could be very simple for small applications, with few users and few different items, however let's suppose the following scenario:

1. application has about 1+ million users (Amazon, eBay, AliExpress etc)
2. all the users want to buy bananas, but its out of stock
3. each user create a restock alert
4. bananas are restocked

For each item restock, the restock alert list must be iterated upon and dispatched accordingly (email, push etc).

How such systems are designed? Which kind of database, tools etc?

Answer (score 4):

User notification systems are typically queue based. Exactly what database is backing the inventory management system doesn't matter that much.

You want two queues, with a flow like this:

1. Inventory update from `0` to `>0` (or whatever a restock is) adds the item to restock alert queue.
2. DB worker consumes items from the restock alert queue, applies business logic, and pushes users to a notification queue.
3. Notification worker consumes users from notification queue and renders/sends emails, push, sms, etc...

Advantages of this design:

- Pushing to the restock alert queue can be implemented in many ways: A SQL DB trigger or stored proc, logic in the load process, or even a chron job that scans the DB.
- A separate restock alert worker minimizes the amount of additional work the inventory DB load process has to do. At the most, it has to add items to a queue.
- Separating the restock alert worker from the notification worker isolates the business logic that defines the restock alerting, allowing integration with an existing notification queue.

Drawbacks of this design:

- Two queues and two workers are required.

Some things to consider

- How important is notification latency? Are people bidding on
  something? Do they need to know *this minute* that it's in stock, or
  will knowing *today* suffice?
- Should notifications ever be batched? How many restock alerts will a user set up? Should someone receive two emails on the same day for different items, or would this be annoying?